# Kafka docker - NoSuchFileException: /opt/kafka.server.keystore.jks

Tags: java, docker, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have installed kafka via docker.
When i run the docker-compose up command I face following errors:

```
 [2022-02-28 08:13:24,185] INFO Awaiting socket connections on localhost:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)

kafka        | [2022-02-28 08:13:24,216] ERROR Modification time of key store could not be obtained: /opt/kafka.server.keystore.jks (org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory)

kafka        | java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/kafka.server.keystore.jks

kafka        |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)

kafka        |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)

kafka        |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)

kafka        |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)

kafka        |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)

kafka        |  at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)

kafka        |  at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)

kafka        |  at java.nio.file.Files.getLastModifiedTime(Files.java:2266)

kafka        |  at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.lastModifiedMs(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:383)

ERROR Modification time of key store could not be obtained: /opt/kafka.server.keystore.jks

Failed to load SSL keystore /opt/kafka.server.keystore.jks of type JKS
```

Below is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'SSL://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'SSL://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: '/opt/kafka.server.keystore.jks'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: 'changeit'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD: 'changeit'
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: '/home/ubuntu/kafka.server.truststore.jks'
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: 'changeit'
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: 'SSL'
    volumes:
      - ./server_certs:/certs
```

Comment: Well ... `NoSuchFileException: /opt/kafka.server.keystore.jks`

Comment: But file is already there in opt folder.

Comment: Prove it? You've never mounted any opt folder into the container. `/home/ubuntu` isn't in the container, either

Comment: How to mount a folder in the container? I have never done it before.

Comment: You already did. See `volumes:` at the end of the file? I was saying that `/opt` is not mounted, only `./server_certs` (of your local computer) is mounted into `/certs` (of the container). In other words, `KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: '/opt/kafka.server.keystore.jks` needs changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the variable values to use `/certs`

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'SSL://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'SSL://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: '/certs/kafka.server.keystore.jks'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: 'changeit'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD: 'changeit'
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: '/certs/kafka.server.truststore.jks'
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: 'changeit'
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: 'SSL'
    volumes:
      - ./server_certs:/certs
```

Comment: How to move truststore and keystore in mounted volume?